# Can .java file be saved as .class file without compilation?

Tags: jar

I am having a jar file from my project. I need to make certain modifications in a particular class. So , I extracted the particular class file , decompiled it and converted it to .java file. I made my changes by editing the .java file through notepad++ and then I saved the file as .class file and added it back to the jar. will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work.

You must have to compile this & add .class file. To compile it successfully you have to add all dependencies.